# Sort a list of strings based on regular expression match

Tags: python, sorting

I have a text file that looks a bit like:

```
random text random text, can be anything blabla %A blabla
random text random text, can be anything blabla %D blabla
random text random text, can be anything blabla blabla %F
random text random text, can be anything blabla blabla
random text random text, %C can be anything blabla blabla
```

When I `readlines()` it in, it becomes a list of sentences. Now I want this list to be sorted by the letter after the `%`. So basically, when the sort is applied to the above, it should look like:

```
random text random text, can be anything blabla %A blabla
random text random text, %C can be anything blabla blabla
random text random text, can be anything blabla %D blabla
random text random text, can be anything blabla blabla %F
random text random text, can be anything blabla blabla
```

Is there a good way to do this, or will I have to break each string in to tubles, and then move the letters to a specific column, and then sort using `key=operator.itemgetter(col)`?

Thank you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
In [1]: def grp(pat, txt): 
   ...:     r = re.search(pat, txt)
   ...:     return r.group(0) if r else '&'

In [2]: y
Out[2]: 
['random text random text, can be anything blabla %A blabla',
 'random text random text, can be anything blabla %D blabla',
 'random text random text, can be anything blabla blabla %F',
 'random text random text, can be anything blabla blabla',
 'random text random text, %C can be anything blabla blabla']

In [3]: y.sort(key=lambda l: grp("%\w", l))

In [4]: y
Out[4]: 
['random text random text, can be anything blabla %A blabla',
 'random text random text, %C can be anything blabla blabla',
 'random text random text, can be anything blabla %D blabla',
 'random text random text, can be anything blabla blabla %F',
 'random text random text, can be anything blabla blabla']
```

Comment: That's the right strategy, but not quite the correct answer, as he needs nonmatched strings to go after matched ones.  A quick fix is to return 'z' + txt for the nonmatch, and 'a' + r.groups()[0] for the match.

Comment: yup, I left the specific sort he wanted as an exercise for the reader - I figured the important bit was the sort(key=...) and grp functions.

Comment: OK, you intrigued me, so I fixed it. Basically, if re.UNICODE is set, the 'z' + s solution may not work; the way I've done it should, I think.

Comment: at the cost of a good deal of complexity, I should add. I think I preferred the previous solution, he can probably use a [null, notnull] set just as easily as a [notnull, null] set.

Comment: Am I the only one a bit confused by the In[] and Out[] notation? What is that?

Comment: r.groups()[0] -- peculiar -- why not just r.group(0)?

Comment: @Tom I just copied from an ipython session (http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) @Alex Because I've just been using groups()[i] for years now and didn't realize there was a group(i) function. (Also it would be group(1), not group(0), right?). Thanks for the note.

Comment: I realized that if I simply include the % at the front of the returned string, the whole thing gets much simpler. & is chr(ord('%')+1), if you're wondering why I chose that. For compatibilty with all encodings, you should probably generate the character that way, but I left it as '&' for simplicity.

Comment: @llimllib, this does a natural sorting but how do you sort numeric (and check if all strings are numbers)?

Answer (score 4):

what about this? hope this helps.

```
def k(line):
    v = line.partition("%")[2]
    v = v[0] if v else 'z' # here z stands for the max value
    return v
print ''.join(sorted(open('data.txt', 'rb'), key = k))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom `key` function to compare the strings. Using the `lambda` syntax you can write that inline, like so:

```
strings.sort(key=lambda str: re.sub(".*%", "", str));
```

The `re.sub(".*%", "", str)` call effectively removes anything before the first percent sign so if the string has a percent sign it'll compare what comes after it, otherwise it'll compare the entire string.

Pedantically speaking, this doesn't just use the letter following the percent sign, it also uses everything after. If you want to use the letter and *only* the letter try this slightly longer line:

```
strings.sort(key=lambda str: re.sub(".*%(.).*", "\\1", str));
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick-and-dirty approach. Without knowing more about the requirements of your sort, I can't know if this satisfies your need.

Assume that your list is held in '`listoflines`':

```
listoflines.sort( key=lambda x: x[x.find('%'):] )
```

Note that this will sort all lines without a '%' character by their final character.

Comment: It'll compare %-less strings by their final characters.