# Sort a list of string in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

Is it possible to sort a list of strings using regex. I have a list of strings that look like the following and i would like to sort them by the version number...

```
_(v\d+)_
```

Current list

```
main_cam_v005_01
main_cam_v001_1001
main_cam_v008_1000
main_cam_v003_305
main_cam_v007_1007
```

Desired list

```
main_cam_v001_1001
main_cam_v003_305
main_cam_v005_01
main_cam_v007_1007
main_cam_v008_1000
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort a list of strings based on regular expression match or something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082413/sort-a-list-of-strings-based-on-regular-expression-match-or-something-similar)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> data = ['main_cam_v005_01',
            'main_cam_v001_1001',
            'main_cam_v008_1000',
            'main_cam_v003_305',
            'main_cam_v007_1007']
>>> sorted(data, key=lambda i: int(re.match(r'main_cam_v(\d+)_\d+', i).group(1)))
['main_cam_v001_1001',
 'main_cam_v003_305',
 'main_cam_v005_01',
 'main_cam_v007_1007',
 'main_cam_v008_1000']
```